# Simulating a tranfer function with opamps

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, transfer-function

I am asked to simulate the following transfer function using operational amplifiers:

[image: Transfer function]

Obviously what it evokes is a second order filter, my question is what kind of filter should I use (Butterworth, Biquad, etc) and how should I calculate the components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange the formula to this: -

H(s) = \$\dfrac{8336.6}{s^2 + s(189.26) + 8952.6}\$

And then note that is of the form: -

H(s) = \$\dfrac{N\cdot\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_n s + \omega_n^2}\$

Numerically derive \$\zeta\$ (damping ratio), \$\omega_n\$ and N and try plugging the values into a sallen key type calculator like this one [here](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm): -

[image]

I plugged a couple of values in (red circles) that seemed appropriate and the TF (blue rectangle) roughly coincides with what you had in your question

Comment: I was wondering, how did you find the 15 Hz frequency?

Comment: @HCalderon \$\omega_n^2\$ = 8952.6 therefore \$\omega_n\$ = 94.618 radians per second = 15.06 Hz

Answer (score 1):

All that you have to do is to add a derivators with gain based on the operational amplifiers.
Assuming that your transfer function is:

Y(s)/E(s)=d/(a*s^^2+b*s+c), where Y is the output and E is the input
In the temporal presentation you have:
Y(t)=(d/c)*E(t)-(b/c)*Y'(t)-(a/c)*Y''(t),
[image]

By using analog derivators and adders you can get the output signal y(t). Replace the blocs and the adders with OPA.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy a particular filter. Using analog computer design ideas you can outright build the filer you have. (some gain tweaking may be required) I was trying to find a good reference for you, this is all i could find. Take a look at chapter 3 elementary analog programming. 
http://www.analogmuseum.org/library/handbook_of_analog_computation.pdf